# Dynamically creating and adding components in initComponent

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I have a view that configures its items dynamically. Those child items also configure themselves dynamically.

I'm trying to use initComponent, but in the code below, the merest presence of initComponent on the childItem results in an error ("Cannot read property 'length' of undefined").

Without initComponent on the childItem, the rest works.

What's going wrong with this? Is there an alternative approach?

```
Ext.define('myapp.view.MyView', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Container',

    initComponent: function () {
        var me = this;

        var childItem = {
            xtype: 'container',

            initComponent: function () {
                var me = this;
                // I want the childItem to do some configuration here.
                me.callParent();
            }
        };

        me.items = [
            childItem
        ];

        me.callParent();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the undocumented `xhooks` config for Components. See [this](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?179010-What-is-xhooks).

```
Ext.ComponentManager.create({
    xtype: 'panel',
    xhooks: {
        initComponent: function() {
            console.log('in local override for this specific instance of panel');
            this.items = [{
                xtype: 'panel',
                xhooks: {
                    initComponent: function() {
                        console.log('in local override for this specific instance of panel');
                        this.items = [{html: 'hi'}];
                        this.callParent();
                    }
                }
            }];
            this.callParent();
        }
    }
}, 'panel');
```

During the component creation process, when Ext sees an `xhooks` property it overrides the current *instance's* functions with the matching functions contained in the `xhooks` config. This ensures that `callParent` works.

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer because it provides a direct solution to the approach shown in my code.

However, I prefer defining the childItem as its own class using the approach described in rixo's and kevhender's answers.

Answer (score 2):

You are not extending an Ext.Container correctly in your code.  If you want to override `initComponent`, use `Ext.define` to define your class first:

```
Ext.define('MyContainer', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    alias: 'widget.my-ct',

    initComponent: function () {
        var me2 = this;
        // I want the childItem to do some configuration here.
        me2.callParent();
    }
});

Ext.define('myapp.view.MyView', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Container',

    initComponent: function () {
        var me = this;

        var childItem = {
            xtype: 'my-ct'
        };

        me.items = [
            childItem
        ];

        me.callParent();
    }
});
```

### EDIT:

As a best practice, you should always define your classes in separate files.  I thought that this would be common sense and just wanted to explain why your original code was in error, but the comment section complained so I've changed this to use more appropriate code.

Comment: -1 Defining something in an `initComponent` is just bad practice.  Every instance will be defining a class when it is created.  Overriding the `initComponent` on the child instance isn't pretty but it is much better.

Comment: @pllee That's stupid to downvote someone for answering the question that is asked. If you really can't cope with the OP trying to do what's he's trying to do, go on and provide an answer with the right way to do it... At least that will be a little constructive.

Comment: @rixo I rarely downvote but if an answer contains something that should never be in production level code I will downvote it.  My second sentence explains the better approach, you already mentioned it in your answer.  Thanks for the insult though.

Comment: Like @rixo said, it was just a suggestion about what would theoretically work.  No need to downvote a valid answer... if I tried to fix everyone's stylistic issues on SO, I'd never get anything done.

Comment: @pllee You're right, my tone was excessive. I'm sorry for that. I must concede *that* was not constructive from me.

Comment: It is not a stylistic issue. It works but it should never be done and there are better ways of handling it.  If it was prefaced with this works but don't do it I wouldn't have downvoted it.  I thought downvotes were to prevent "bad" (it is answering a non-trivial problem and it works, everything else looks fine but the bad part is really bad) code from spreading.

Comment: No, you could have left the answer alone.  Downvoting is for WRONG answers. My answer was a RIGHT answer that explained why what he was doing was wrong, and gave an solution that would work.

Comment: Downvoting is also for possibly dangerous answers. Dangerous can have multiple meanings

Comment: Sure, but my answer was not "dangerous".

Comment: I have edited the answer, since there was so much complaining about it.

Comment: I guess we can agree to disagree, no hard feelings.  The class will be defined `n` number of times when it only needs to be done once.  There is a better alternative that I mentioned that avoids defining a class altogether. I think that `Ext` should be throwing an error if you define a class that overrides a previous class or `xtype`.  I also think that defining a class every time in the `initComponent` goes against what that method should be used for but that is just my opinion.

Comment: As I've said, I agree that it should not be done.  My original answer was only to be used as an illustration of WHY the original answer would not work.  Also as I said, I have modified the response to be more of a fully usable answer.

Answer (score 0):

`callParent` will work only with methods that have been passed through `Ext.define` (or a close equivalent). Here, you're doing a "runtime" override, so `callParent` won't work for the children.

Your most next-developer-friendly option is to turn those into legitimate Ext overrides. You can use anonymous classes for simplicity's sake. Example:

```
var childClass = Ext.define(null, {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Container'

    ,initComponent: function() {

        // Here that will work
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});

var childItem = new childClass;

// ...
```

The other option is to do the work of `callParent` yourself by calling the parent method in the right scope. The catch here is that you must know how to access the parent method, however this option is nice for bragging about your javascript skills since it will result in some barbarian syntax most (non javascript) developers won't be able to figure out ;) In your case, replace `this.callParent()` in your child with:

```
Ext.container.Container.prototype.initComponent.apply(this, arguments);
```

In both cases, don't forget that you must require `Ext.container.Container`. In the first case, that will ensure the code runs synchronously, and in the second case it will avoid it to crash on undefined class.

Comment: It is not well known but you can actually do a `callParent` on instances.  There is logic in Ext.override to handle instances where this.callParent() will call the original instances function. `var btn = new Ext.Button(); Ext.override(btn, {update: function(){console.log(arguments);this.callParent(arguments);}})`